# React Native erro no react-navigation-stack no Android

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Ola, eu já tentei resolver este problema com varias soluções e nada, da-me sempre o mesmo erro.

Fiz todos os procedimentos que me diz la no site dele para eu fazer, [createStackNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html), e mesmo assim o erro está aparece.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui embaixo estão as dependencias que estou utilizar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma das soluções que já tentei foi dar **downgrade** as dependencias, mas no meu caso não ajudou.

Também já coloquei os codigos necessarios na pasta do android.
Este problema só dá quando eu coloco o `react-navigation-stack`
no meu ficheiro de rotas js.

```
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

import White from './pages/White';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import Main from './pages/Main';

const AppScreen = createStackNavigator({ Main });
const NoAuthScreen = createStackNavigator({ Login });

export default createAppContainer(
    createSwitchNavigator(
        {
            White,
            AppScreen,
            NoAuthScreen
        },
        {
            initialRouteName: 'White',
        }
    )
);
```

Se eu tirar o `react-navigation-stack` do import do meu ficheiro o problema desaparece e o app funciona corretamente, mas eu preciso mesmo do `react-navigation-stack` para fazer a minha app, pois quero fazer a parte de auth nas rotas e estou a seguir o que me diz neste [site](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/pt-BR/auth-flow.html) para eu fazer.

Quem poder ajudar eu agredeço muito, pois ainda estou no inicio do projeto e já está a dar erros que eu não consigo preceber o porque. Obrigado.

Comment: O que adicionou na pasta do android? Desfaz que vai funcionar. No react native 0.60 ou superior não é necessario mais usar o link para muitos pacotes. Esse pacote do react native navigation mais os auxiliares o link é feito automatico. Não esqueça de adicionar na secção scripts de package.json isso `"postinstall": "npx jetify"`

Comment: O que eu adicionei na pasta android foi o que é pedido ao instalar o `react-native-gesture-handler` [Getting Started](https://kmagiera.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/getting-started.html#android).

Comment: Consegui resolver o meu problema! Depois de ter lido melhor o docs do _[React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/3.x/getting-started.html)_ reparei que na versão 3 ele já traz o `createStackNavigator` no import dele, e como não provocou o erro, posso considerar  que o meu problema está resolvido. Claro que seria bom conseguir utilizar a versão mais atualizada mas como está a funcionar bem vou deixar assim. Depois devo atualizar o post so com os procedimentos que fiz. Obrigado.

Comment: E tá vindo atualização nova do React Navigation ai em. A versão 5 está em beta :)

Answer (score 0):

Pela descrição do erro, faltou fazer o link da biblioteca "react-native-gesture-handler" com o seu projeto.  Esta biblioteca já faz parte do seu arquivo "package-json".

Faça o seguinte:

```
react-native link react-native-gesture-handler
```

E depois instale novamente:

```
react-native run-android
```

Comment: Na versão do react native que ele está usando não é necessario usar o link!